# apt-get stopped working

Tags: apt

When trying to install anything:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 colord : Depends: libsane (>= 1.0.11-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried running `apt-get -f install` and `apt-get install libsane` with no luck.

Comment: Maybe, libsane is not published for your Ubuntu release. In terminal, run command "lsb_release -a" and provide the results.

Comment: Please post output of `apt-get -f install` and `apt-cache showpkg libsane | head -n3`

Comment: apt-cache showpkg libsane | head -n3  
    Package: libsane  
    Versions:  
    1.0.22-7ubuntu1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/ubuntu.mirrors.ovh.net_ftp.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)

Comment: http://pastie.org/8791255

Comment: I went into /var/lib/dpkg/status and searched for libsane and removed it's entires. After that ran `apt-get -f install` and it reinstall it and now it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo rm /etc/sane.d/abaton.conf /var/cache/apt/archives/libsane_1.0.22-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb` (it will force redownloading of libsane), then try again `apt-get -f install`